# Gulp & Webpack: webpack-stream working with non-existent file

Tags: webpack, gulp

In this problem, `Gulp` and `Webpack` are integrated by `Webpack-stream`, so the instructions for `Webpack` included in `gulpfile.js`. Currently, I use webpack 3.4.1 and webpack-stream 4.0.0.

```
const   gulp = require('gulp'),
        gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
        webpackStream = require('webpack-stream'),
        webpack = webpackStream.webpack,
        named = require('vinyl-named');
```

I need to define the conditional output, then created the function inside `gulp.dest()`. Thanks to `vynil-named`, we don't need to define the entry points, however to define the output condition, we need to know where file gotten from (it may be `public` or `admin` paths, for example).

Inside `gulp.dest()`, it says that file gotten from `C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\someEntryPoint.js`, however actually this file is in `C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\source\public\js\someEntryPoint.js`:

```
gulp.task('webpack', function(){

    /*  Entry points locations:
        C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\source\public\js
        C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\source\admin\js  */

    return gulp.src('source')
        .pipe(named())
        .pipe(webpackStream())
        .pipe(gulp.dest( file => {

            console.log('path: '+ file.path);
            // Output to console: "path: C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\someEntryPoint.js"
            // Real file path:          C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\source\public\js\someEntryPoint.js
```

Before I ask "How to define desired output paths?", I need to understand what's going on. I defined the output paths for `pug` and `sass` by same way: nothing like this happened.

---

### Update

The answer should be here, in the end `webpack-stream`'s `index.js`...

```
function prepareFile (fs, compiler, outname) {
  var path = fs.join(compiler.outputPath, outname);
  if (path.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
    path = path.split('?')[0];
  }

  var contents = fs.readFileSync(path);

  var file = new File({
    base: compiler.outputPath,
    path: nodePath.join(compiler.outputPath, outname),
    contents: contents
  });
  return file;
}
```

Comment: If you replace `console.log('path: '+ file.path);` with `console.log('path: '+ file.dirname+'/'+file.basename);` does it make any difference?

Comment: @lofihelsinki, only one difference -
 last backslash: (`C:\MyIde\projects\testProj/someEntryPoint.js"` instead of `C:\MyIde\projects\testProj\someEntryPoint.js"`).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **webpack** integration with **vynil-fs** streams is limited, and we can not do anything with files after `.pipe(webpackStream())`. However, "gulp and webpack integration" don't mean "gulp and vynil-js integration", and we can write own wrapper for **webpack** to make it compatible with `gulp`:

```
const gulplog = require('gulplog'),
      path = require('path'),
      notifier = require('node-notifier'),
      webpack = require('webpack');

gulp.task('webpack', callback => {

    let WebpackOptions = {

      entry: // define your entry points...

      output: {
          path: // define your output path...
          filename: '[name].js'
      }

      watch: // define watch mode depenend on build...
    };

    webpack(WebpackOptions, (error, statistics) => {

      if (!error) {
        error = statistics.toJson().errors[0];
      }

      if (error) {

        notifier.notify({
          title: 'webpack',
          message: error
        });

        gulplog.error(error);

      } else {

        gulplog.info(statistics.toString({
            colors: true
        }));
      }


      if (!WebpackOptions.watch && error) {
        // for production build
        callback(error);
      }
      else {
        callback();
      }
    });
});
```